# How to write test case for this method where try and catch code is cover?

Tags: unit-test, community, test-setup

```
@RemoteAction
public Static List < Document__c > GetMarketingDocuments(string opportunityId) {
    try {
        string queryString = '';
        List < DroisysOne__Document__c > docs = null;
        string qString = 'Select PLN_BRAND__c  Priority__c where id=:opportunityId';
        List < Priority__c > lstFileCode = database.Query(qString);
        string brandCode = '';
        if (lstFileCode.size() > 0) {
            brandCode = lstFileCode[0].DroisysOne__PLN_BRAND__c;
            queryString = 'Select Id,Title__c,Description__c,DocumentType__c,FileType__c,GeneratedDate__c,FilelinkedCode__c,ContentUrl__c from Document__c Where FileLinkedCode__c=:brandCode '; //AND DocumentType__c=:docType
            docs = database.Query(queryString);
        }
        return (docs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorLog.createErrorRecord(e.getStackTraceString(), e.getMessage(), e.getTypeName());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you

Answer (score 1):

One way to make that throw an exception would be to pass in a invalid id as the parameter i.e. call the following in your test:

```
GetMarketingDocuments('notAnId')
```

This would throw a QueryException, then you can check for the error log that it looks like your code would create.

Comment: it is not working.when I passed wrong ID  in this method.GetMarketingDocuments('12dcsfdsfte4123') but it is not throw exception

Comment: It definitely ought to throw an exception... ordinarily it would. Have you looked at the code coverage for the test? Obviously, the exception won't come all the way up to your test method. Can you provide your whole test code?

Comment: Sir code length is too large so i am not  able to comment here .Please Provide me your email Id for code send purpose.